# Add Ubuntu to Windows 10 boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Here is my situation. I originally (only) have Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Then, I installed Windows 10 into a free partition. Now, even though Ubuntu's partitions remained, I'm not able to enter Ubuntu when booting. I'm expecting this to happen when I was installing Windows 10, but I don't know how to add the existing Ubuntu to boot menu to fix it. It's fine for me either the boot menu is GRUB or Windows.

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode or both in BIOS boot mode? Post this: `sudo parted -l` If both are in same boot mode: `sudo update-grub` will add Windows to grub menu.

Comment: I discovered that I can enter both OS in BIOS. I don't need a boot loader.